# SLES 15 zypper and yast error

Tags: sles

I've created a predefined SLES 15.1 Linux VM on GCP.

SUSEConnect, zypper and yast functionalites don't work.

I always have the error: "11-Resource temporarily unavailable"

For example, I run the command:

```
# SUSEConnect -p sle-module-basesystem/15.1/x86_64
```

Result:

```
Registering system to registration proxy https://smt-gce.susecloud.net
Updating system details on https://smt-gce.susecloud.net ...
Activating sle-module-basesystem 15.1 x86_64 ...
-> Adding service to system ...
command 'zypper --non-interactive refs Basesystem_Module_x86_64' failed
Error: zypper returned (1) with 'Unexpected exception.
Unknown error reading from 'plugin:/susecloud?credentials=Basesystem_Module_x86_64&path=/services/1772'
History:
 - Receive: script died unexpectedly
 - [11-Resource temporarily unavailable]

Please file a bug report about this.
See http://en.opensuse.org/Zypper/Troubleshooting for instructions.'
```

Please, can some one help me to solve this issue?
I need to install some extra packages in this SLES.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the lxml configuration file with version 4.4.2. So uninstall and install the newer version 4.6.2 and re-register using the below commands.

```
# pip freeze | grep lxml
# pip uninstall lxml
# pip install lxml
# /usr/sbin/registercloudguest --force-new
# zypper update
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found the problem.. when I run: zypper update     I was wrong... I selected "no" when it asked if I accepted the license contract...